# Angular-cli doesn't load styles when using symlinks

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

I have an Angular 2 app running with `angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.21`. At the begining of development I ran into this issue, where no styles were being loaded. I'm using SASS, which was being compiled just fine into the styles.bundle.js but I got no styles in my app. I tried and tried to fix it but had to start all over again with a new template. Everything has been working ok.

Today I ran `ng serve` and now it's happening again. Last night when I went to bed it was fine. I haven't updated anything at all.

**Does anyone know why this is happening?** Is it some kind of cache? Even running `ng build` gives the same result.

**UPDATE:**

I've managed to fix this. I had moved the entire directory to a different location. Moving it back seems to have done the trick. **I still don't know why this is happening** though. I tried searching for the path in all the files but nothing came up. I *still* don't know why this is happening though. This means now that I can't decide to move my app to a different location in the future.

I'm using Windows 10

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.21
node: 6.9.1
os: win32 x64
```

I generated the project using `ng new <projec_name>`.

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is my `angular-cli.json`. I don't see anything here that would be affected by moving the entire project to another folder.

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-alpha.2",
    "name": "core-ui"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": "assets",
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "scss/style.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js",
        "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"
      ],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "prefixInterfaces": false
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 3:**

I've found that I was mistaken whith my first findings. Moving the directory is not the cause of the problem; **its symlinks**. If from the command line I navigate to the root directory via a symlink, no styles are loaded. If I navigate to the correct physical path everything works fine.

**TL;DR**

Angular-cli will not load and apply styles if you navigate to the directory using symlinks on Windows. Why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

When generating a new project you can also define which extension you want for style files:

```
ng new <projec_name> --style=sass
```

Or set the default style on an existing project:

```
ng set defaults.styleExt scss
```

For more info you can go to here:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Comment: The starter template I was using was infact configured this way. Like I said, the sass was being compiled, but it was not being applied to the html. And apparently the thing that caused it was moving the directory elsewhere. I would like to understand why that is. Thanks though.

Comment: Maybe try to upload angular-cli?